# VB.Net Faster way of summing values in an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Currently I use a for loop for summing the values stored in a byte array type:

```
Dim values As Byte() = {1, 23, 42, 12, 9, 102, 86, 0, 0, 0, 0, etc...}
Dim sum As Integer
For Each value As Byte In values
     If value = 0 Then
          Exit For
     End If
     sum += value
Next
```

Since this is a part of a function that is called multiple times a second, is there a faster/more efficient way of summing the values stored in an array?

Comment: Start using real numbers and not strings for your BYTE array. Everytime you read a value from that array and use it as a number the compiler add an hidden conversion for your convenience. Option Strict should always be set to ON

Comment: Turn on Option Strict - that wont even compile.  `"1"` is string, not byte

Comment: How big is the array?  How many times is "multiple times a second"?  Have you actually measurably checked to see if this is the actual slow part of your code?  What you've posted should be able to be run _many many_ times a second without any noticeable effects.

Comment: The array has 104 elements, multiple times a second = ~10000 times a second, performance profiling shows it accounts for 10.6% of the total processor time.

Comment: Ok.  How much do the contents of the array change?  Could you wrap it in a class that's aware of the total sum and recalculates the sum only when the contents change, based on just the changes, rather than recalculating the whole lot etc? Or is it an entirely different 104 elements each time?